# Prove that all the roots of $\cos z=a$, where $−1 \leq a \leq 1$, are real.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to apply how I solved this question for $\sin z = a$, but I ran into a small issue.

$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} = a$. Then, if we state $w = e^{iz}$, then we obtain $w + \frac{1}{w} = 2a$, hence $w^2 + 1 = 2aw$. By use of the quadratic formula, the roots of $w^2 - 2aw + 1 = 0$ are $a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 1}$. Since $ -1 \leq a \leq 1$, we know $\sqrt{a^2 - 1}$ is imaginary (except for the cases of $-1, 1$). Next, $|w| = \sqrt{a^2 + (\pm \sqrt{a^2 - 1})^2} = \sqrt{2a^2-1}$. This is when I run into the problem. When I solved this problem for $\sin z = a$, $|w| = 1$, which made it very easy to work with because $|w| = |e^{iz}| = 1$, hence $z$ is purely real. However, I don't know how to proceed when $|w| = \sqrt{2a^2-1}$.

Comment: If you have already proved it for the sine, why not just apply $\cos z = \sin(z+\pi/2)$?

Comment: Note that the modulus of $w$ is not $\sqrt{a^2+(\pm\sqrt{a^2-1})^2}$. In fact $|w|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, where $w=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}=x+iy$ and $\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}=iy$, so $y=\pm i\sqrt{a^2-1}=\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, that would conclude the proof because $z + \frac{\pi}{2}$ is and will always be a real number, (assuming z is a real number).

Comment: @walcher, how did you manage to just tack the $i$ onto $\sqrt{a^2 -1 }$? Furthermore, if I square $\pm i\sqrt{a^2-1}$, I could see it potentially working, but I was under the impression that in modulus, you don't include the $i$.

Comment: @David Since $\lvert a\rvert \leqslant 1$, you have $\sqrt{a^2-1} = \pm i\sqrt{1-a^2}$, and thus $\lvert w\rvert^2 = a^2 + (\sqrt{1-a^2})^2 = 1$.

Comment: I see, thanks. that should be it.